# CSS attribute selectors in JSX with TypeScript

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I can do the following in pure HTML/CSS

```html
<div color="red">
  red
</div>

<div color="yellow">
  yellow
</div>
```

```css
div[color="red"] {
  color: red;
}

div[color="yellow"] {
  color: yellow;
}
```

However, using React and TypeScript, I want to do something like this:

```js
const Colored = ({ color }: { color: "yellow" | "red" ) => (
    <div color={color}>
        { color }
    </div>
);
```

However, I can't add abritrary props to `div`!!
so we could do exactly the same as the above, but instead

```js
<Colored color="red" />
<Colored color="yellow" />
```

How can I do something like this? Additionally, should I even be doing this? Is there a better way of doing this in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case using the type `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>` you can pass additional properties to the `DIV` mantaining your component `Colored`.

```
type IColoredProps =  { color: "yellow" | "red" } & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
     
const Colored: FC<IColoredProp> = (props) => (
    <div {...props}>
        {props.color}
    </div>
);
```

Now the color is mandatory and can only be "red" or "yellow", and you can pass the rest of properties a normal `div` can have.

```
<Colored style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} color="red"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-http-vikf0z?file=/src/App.tsx) example for you :

- instead of `<Colored text="red" />` you should use `<Colored color="red" />`